# video brightness going down (dull) in rare camera record

Tags: android

why am getting low brightness during video record in rare camera? image is fine.

below is my code for preparing the mediarecorder for video. please help

```
try {
        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mVideoMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        // Step 2: Set sources
        mVideoMediaRecorder.setAudioSource     (MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mVideoMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mVideoMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(mCurrentCameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        mVideoMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mCameraPreview.getVideoSize().width, mCameraPreview.getVideoSize().height);
```

mVideoMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoPath);

```
        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mVideoMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getSurfaceHolder().getSurface());
        mVideoMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mCameraPreview.getPreviewOrientation());

        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mVideoMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
```

Comment: happening in some device ex: Lenovo TAB3 & Essential.